# how to use unnecessary onClick event?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to properly use unnecessary onClick events ?

```
interface IUIText {
    children: ReactNode;
    type: string;
    onClick?: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => void;
}
const UIText = (props: IUIText) => {
    return (
        <div onClick={(e) => props.onClick(e)}> //Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.
            {props.children}
        </div>
    );
};
```

**Usage:**

```
 <UIText type={'solid'} onClick={e => clickHandler(e)}>Gallery</UIText>
```

**But i can also use it without onClick event:**

```
 <UIText type={'primary'}>Gallery</UIText>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to perform a null check. Your onClick is not 'unnecessary' but 'nullable'

```
interface IUIText {
    children: ReactNode;
    type: string;
    onClick?: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => void;
}
const UIText = (props: IUIText) => {
    return (
        <div onClick={(e) => {
           if(props.onClick) props.onClick(e); // just check for onClick
        }}>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: You can also use the `?` operator: `props.onClick?.call(this, e)` (unfortunately, I don't think you can skip `call` and go `onClick?(e)`).

Answer (score 2):

You can also do the check with a logical AND (&&)

```
interface IUIText {
    children: ReactNode;
    type: string;
    onClick?: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => void;
}
const UIText = (props: IUIText) => {
    return (
        <div onClick={(e) => props.onClick && props.onClick(e)}> 
            {props.children}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: already did it =)